Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Chinese Language Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

For which senses of simplified 制 would I use the traditional form 製?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


What is the grammar of "用餐曅請隨手整理桌面 座位有限請勿休憩估用"?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


How is 得 used in this sentence？

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)


How to address a teacher one knows well (in conversation and emails). Is 亲爱 "dear" ever appropriate?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


What does 二货朋友 mean?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)


Never understood the usage of 弄

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


What are the most usual Chinese terms for permanent markers vs. whiteboard markers

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


What is the conclusion of this article?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)


How you say... I feel good after finally getting closure

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


What does the sound "app" mean in Chinese?

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)


A short summary stating the objectives of the site (i.e. welcomed question topics) would be useful for first time users.

We already have one here: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Thanks. That's great; however, I was thinking of something short, snappy, simply stated on the main page. This would be useful for the new user and the speed reader, although this may go against general formatting of stackexchange websites. Having to navigate through the help menu to discover the types of questions to ask may not be intuitive for some new users.

The current batch of questions and answers makes this site seem to be more about Chinese-English translation than the Chinese language.
